# deploying java web app without netbeans locally

Tags: java, apache, web-deployment

i have a java web application that i want to deploy locally.

how am i supposed to do that without running it through netbeans?

do i have anything to download? does xampp or wampserver can do that?

i am using apache tomcat server. and how can i change the url from ipaddress:8084/mywebapp to mywebapp only. or the browser needs the ip and port to access the web app.

when i installed netbeans it has apache tomcat server already can i use that as my host even not running netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html

1- install apache tomcat (http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi).

2- may be you need to change windows path (for connection between JVM and web server).

3- run apache tomcat(..\Apache Tomcat 7.x.xx\bin\tomcatx.exe).

3- copy and pase '..\dist\mywebapp.war' to Apache Tomcat 7.x.xx\webapp folder)

if web server (if work truly) move this file to work dir.